# Change CSS class programmatically on load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have two pages, let's call them "receipts.com" and "business.receipts.com". Both link to a page on a different domain via Response.Redirect("http://receipts2.com/default.aspx?mode=")
where the "mode"-parameter is the referring page.

The recieving page should look in the query string, and choose a different CSS class according to the "mode"-parameter.

How is this accomplished? And is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of swapping class names you can use the same class and different stylesheets. 
There are two ways to handle stylesheets: client side and server side.

On the client side, you can [parse the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and disable stylesheets using: `(document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]).disabled = true;`

On the server side, you can use [themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) or simply add a placeholder around the style declarations and show/hide them using codebehind that looks at `Response.QueryString["mode"]`:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder1" runat="server" Visible="false">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/alternate.css" media="all" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and code behind in a master page somewhere:

```
if(Response.QueryString["mode"] == "blah")
{
  placeHolder1.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.referrer` instead of passing in the page via querystring.

When you say "The receiving page should look in the query string, and choose a different CSS class", what is that class going to be set against, ie the body or an element like p?

Plain Javascript

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = " yourClass";
```

jQuery

```
$("p").addClass("yourClass");
```

Perhaps you meant a css theme?

and then you could try

```
if (document.referrer == "blahblah")
  document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='one.css' />)
else
  document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='two.css' />)
```

Although I would recommend looking into jQuery

```
$.get(stylesheet, function(contents){
  $("<style type=\"text/css\">" + contents + "</style>").appendTo(document.head);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use different [Page-Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx):

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (Request.QueryString["mode"])
    {
        case "receipts.com":
            Page.Theme = "DefaultTheme";
            break;
        case "business.receipts.com":
            Page.Theme = "BusinessTheme";
            break;
    }
}
```

Of course you can also use the code above to apply different [Css-Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) to controls.

Comment: I think I'll give this a try. And the Page_PreInit is the right place to place this code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

u can do something like this

```
    {
string hrefstring = null;

string mode = this.Page.Request.QueryString.Item("mode");


if (mode == "a") {
    hrefstring = ("~/yourcss/a.css");

} else if (mode == "b") {
    hrefstring = ("~/yourcss/b.css");
}

css.Href = ResolveClientUrl(hrefstring);
css.Attributes("rel") = "stylesheet";
css.Attributes("type") = "text/css";
css.Attributes("media") = "all";

Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
    }
```